# "<file-type> is meant for <application>" vs "<file-type> is dedicated for <application>" vs ...?

Tags: phrase-requests

Which phrase should I use if I want to say that particular group of files should be used with particular software/tool/script? Should I - for example - say that "mp3 files are meant for music players", "mp3 files are dedicated for music players" or maybe some other way?

In the `CHANGELOG.md` of my project I want to mention the addition of several `*.csv` files which are going to be fed into a particular *python* script (which is part of the project), something like:

> Added `*.csv` files meant for `generateChipYaml.py` ...

However this doesn't sound right to me, but all the other options I could think of are not better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some options/examples:

- ".mp3 files can be decoded and played by music player applications"
- "files with the .csv extension can be processed by generateChipYaml.py"
- "files with the .csv extension can be used as inputs to generateChipYaml.py"
- "generateChipYaml.py takes its input in the form of .csv files"
- "generateChipYaml.py processes .csv files"
- "the .csv files I've added can be used as input to generateChipYaml.py"